# Solve $-y''=e^x$ with $y(0)=y(1)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Fine the displacement for an exponential force, $-y''=e^x$ with  $y(0)=y(1)=0$

To solve this problem, I used integration twice  gives me 
$$\int\left(\int -e^xdx\right)dx=-e^x+c_1x+c_2=y(x)$$ Then plug in initial condition I have $y(x)=1-x+ex-e^x$.

Is there a way that I don't need to do double integration?

Comment: You could do [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negative is only important when it comes to the inhomogeneous solution. Since you have (essentially) $y'' = 0$ for the homogeneous part, the solution is a constant.  But because it's second order there is a multiplicity thus the general solutions is $y_H(x) = A + Bx$.  Next use [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) to find the inhomogeneous solution.  Assume it has the form of the inhomogeneous part, $y_I(x) = Ae^x$:

$$
y_I'(x) = Ae^x \\
y_I''(x) = Ae^x
$$

Plug into the diff. eq:

$$
-Ae^x = e^x \\
-Ae^x - e^x = 0 \\
e^x(-A - 1) = 0 \\
-A - 1 = 0 \\
A = -1
$$

This leads to the inhomogeneous solution of $y_I(x) = -e^x$.  Add this to the homogeneous solution to get the general solution:

$$
y(x) = A + Bx - e^x
$$

Finally use your initial conditions to find $A$ and $B$:

$$
y(0) = A - 1 = 0 \rightarrow A = 1\\
y(1) = A + B - e = 0 \rightarrow 1 + B - e = 0 \rightarrow B = e - 1
$$

So the final solution is:

$$
y(x) = 1 + (e - 1)x - e^x
$$